# Reusing the same v-app in vue

Tags: vuejs2

I have the below pug/html:

```
            table.accountinfo.table.table-sm
              thead.thead
                tr 
                  th #
                  th Name
                  th Address
                  th Balance
              tbody
                tr(v-for="account in accounts") 
                  td {{account.accountID}}
                  td {{account.name}}
                  td
                    span(title='{{account.accountAddress}}').ellipsisoverflow {{account.accountAddress}}
                  td
                    span {{account.balance}}
            table.accountinfo.table.table-sm
              thead.thead
                tr 
                  th #
                  th Name
                  th Address
                  th Balance
              tbody
                tr(v-for="account in accounts") 
                  td {{account.accountID}}
                  td {{account.name}}
                  td
                    span(title='{{account.accountAddress}}').ellipsisoverflow {{account.accountAddress}}
                  td
                    span {{account.balance}}
```

And the below vue script:

```
var accountinfo = new Vue({
    el: '.accountinfo',
    data: {
        accounts: []
    }
});
```

When I open my html file only the first table is correctly created (mutiple rows with the correct data). The second table however is not created correctly and shows the values including the brackets (and thus are not replaced bye vue). I assume this is the case as the same v-app is used twice. How can I configure this so both elements/tables are correctly created using the same v-app?

Comment: Where do you use `v-model`?

Comment: The first problem with your code is you can't mount 1 vue app to more than 1 element!

Comment: V-model should be v-app, I have updated this in the question.  The problem you described is actually my question, I would like to mount 1 vue app to multiple elements. Is this possible in anyway or is this not an option?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's written specifically anywhere but as per the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering) linking is done with ids, this is to ensure that one vue instance is only linked to 1 root element.

It's not possible to mount 1 app on multiple elements.

In line with your edit, you have a couple of ways to do what you want:

1. Change the selector for the second form and register another Vue instance with that Id.
2. Have one wrapping container that the Vue instance is registered to then each table can read from the same `accounts` variable.